# Generating all combinations of replaced strings

Tags: python, string, replace, substring

I have a fairly specific programming question that has been bugging me for a of couple weeks now, and I believe this is the right place to ask.

I need a function that can generate all combinations of various substrings being replaced in a larger string, for example;

```py
thisfunction([['Hello','hi'],['Goodbye','bye'],['Hello','goodbye']], "This is a string that says Hello and Goodbye and Hello again")
```

Should return

```py
["String that says Hello, Goodbye and Hello again",
"String that says hi and Goodbye and Hello again",
"String that says hi and bye and Hello again",
"String that says Hello and bye and Hello again",
"String that says Hello, Goodbye and goodbye again",
"String that says hi and Goodbye and goodbye again",
"String that says hi and bye and goodbye again",
"String that says Hello and bye and goodbye again",]
```

I tried various strategies with regex and the replace function but with no success
All ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Your list `['Hello','hi'],['Goodbye','bye'],['Hello','goodbye']]` contains `'Hello'` twice; am I correct to assume that this means only first occurence of `Hello` in the string should be replaced by `hi` and only the second one by `goodbye`?

Comment: @Błotosmętek correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to achieve something like:

```
from itertools import product

def thisfunction(lst, s):
    for p in product(*lst):
        yield s.format(*p)

>>> list(thisfunction([['Hello','hi'],['Goodbye','bye'],['Hello','goodbye']], 
                      "This is a string that says {} and {} and {} again"))
['This is a string that says Hello and Goodbye and Hello again',
 'This is a string that says Hello and Goodbye and goodbye again',
 'This is a string that says Hello and bye and Hello again',
 'This is a string that says Hello and bye and goodbye again',
 'This is a string that says hi and Goodbye and Hello again',
 'This is a string that says hi and Goodbye and goodbye again',
 'This is a string that says hi and bye and Hello again',
 'This is a string that says hi and bye and goodbye again']
```

Comment: To make it completely compatible with OP's example you could add replacing first items from each sublist with `{}` in `s`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek True. However,  that would clutter the code a bit, and I think the OP should rather use placeholders in the string.

Comment: Anyway it is a one-liner: `for first, *rest in lst: s = s.replace(first, '{}')`

Comment: @Błotosmętek and I don't quite understand where i would put this line, could you edit the code above to reflect how it would look, cluttered code is not a worry at the moment :)

Comment: @Błotosmętek Not really. For startersm that wouldn't produce the desired list. Also, "Hello" is repeated, so the second list will just be ignored.

Comment: this works well enough for me, although i did have to modify it

Comment: @Błotosmętek pls don't add a logically different approach into an existing answer. Why not post an answer of your own.

Comment: @schwobaseggl as you wish, I thought it is too similar to warrant a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product

def thisfunction(lst, s):
    for first, *rest in lst:
        s = s.replace(first, '{}', 1)
    for p in product(*lst):
        yield s.format(*p)

print(list(thisfunction([['Hello','hi'],['Goodbye','bye'],['Hello','goodbye']], "This is a string that says Hello and Goodbye and Hello again")))
```

Comment: Now in plain sight, I get you :D

Comment: technically the better answer, a modified version of @schwobaseggl 's I'll upvote but not accept